# Angular routing with dynamic prefix

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular-module

I have a success page that I want to redirect to after certain actions.
Currently my url would just be localhost:4200/success after redirecting but I would like my url to append the /success to whatever path I am currently being redirected from because my succes page is generic and receives its data from the redirecting component.

Example:
while writing a review my url would be localhost:4200/review, after successfully posting a review I wish to redirect to my success page while turning the url into localhost:4200/review/success

How can I dynamically prefix a path in Angular ?

My lazy loaded routing-module would look something like this:

```
{
    path: 'review',
    loadChildren: () => import('./review/review.module').then(m => m.ReviewModule)
},
{
    path: 'order',
    loadChildren: () => import('./order/order.module').then(m => m.OrderModule)
},{
    path: 'succes',
    loadChildren: () => import('./succes/succes.module').then(m => m.SuccesModule)
},
```

SuccesModule:

```
const succesRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: SuccesComponent },
```

];

Answer (score 0):

Just asking, but why you want to implement such a design pattern? On the top of my head it doesn't seem a good idea. What happens if user manually enters `localhost:4200/review/success` and he isn't redirected from anywhere, what should then happen?

Typycally a queryParam (e.g id) would be added to the url of the item on post success. This has two functions, indicating that posting was posted successfully and you have a url to navigate to.

https://angular.io/start/start-routing#associate-a-url-path-with-a-component

```js
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: ProductListComponent },
      { path: 'products/:productId', component: ProductDetailsComponent },
    ])
```

```
https://getting-started-myfork.stackblitz.io/products/1
```

Comment: Currently navigating to the url manually redirects you back to home (happens when success receives no input data). How would you suggest setting up the route instead in this case? using queryparams in my SuccesModule for each possible redirect?

edit: reason for this approach would be because of indexing by google

Comment: Yeah, SEO wise that would be an alternative. Possible to use route wildcard asterisk? `{ path: '*/success', component: SuccesComponent }`

Comment: So this works as expected:
const successRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: SuccessComponent },
 { path: 'review/:id', component: SuccessComponent },
];

However this leaves me with the url: /success/review/id. Tried using a wildcard as below but it did not work:

const successRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: SuccessComponent },
 { path: '*/success', component: SuccessComponent },
];